# addaxis matlab axis range change

Tags: matlab, plot, range, setting

I use addaxis function http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9016-addaxis (I need 4 different y axis), but I don't know how to set axis range for added axis.

I need the "1" value of first axis at the position of "0" value of second axis.

The simplest code for demonstrating problem is:

```
figure
plot([-1,-1],[1,1],'k'),
axis([0,3,0,3]);
addaxis([2,3],[2,3]);
axis([0,3,0,3]); % Doesn't work
```

If there isn't simpler way, can anybody suggest addaxis function modification?

Thanks a lot for answers

Comment: can you provide a picture of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Here is the picture of graph https://db.tt/8lRVUFEn thanks a lot.